# Сравнить значение массива в цикле foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Необходимо в цикле `foreach` проверить значение массива на текущей итерации с последуйщей.

К примеру мой цикл: `foreach ($products as $product)`

И нужно текущее поле `$product['model']` сравнить с следуйщим. Как написать условие?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Гораздо проще сравнивать с предыдущей.

```
$last = null;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if($product['model'] === $last){
        echo "YES!";
    }
    $last = $product['model'];
}
```

Если прям надо со следующим, то

```
reset($products);
for($i = 0; $i < count($products) - 1; ++$i) {
    $current = current($products);
    $next = next($products);
    if ($current['model'] === $next['model']) {
        echo "YES!";
    }
}
```

Сравнивать с предыдущим и последующим

```
$last = null;
reset($products);
for($i = 0; $i < count($products) - 1; ++$i) {
    $current = current($products);
    $next = next($products);
    if ($current['model'] === $next['model']) {
        echo "NEXT MATCHES";
    }
    if ($current['model'] === $last) {
        echo "LAST MATCHES";
    }
    $last = $current['model'];
}
```

Comment: мне просто в цикле нужны будут сравнения как с предыдущим так и с следующим значением. Можете еще подсказать условия сравнения с предыдущим в цикле for?

Comment: Скомбинировать первый вариант со вторым :)

Comment: Логично (: спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы не использовать классический цикл `while`?

Например вот так:

```
reset($products);
while($current = current($products)) {
    $next = next($products);
    if ($next && $next['model'] === $current['model']) {
        echo('Same');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете индексный массив, то проще всего воспользоваться циклом `for`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($products) - 1; $i++) {
    if($products[$i]['model'] === $products[$i + 1]['model']) {
        echo('Same');
    }
}
```

Comment: потому что массив может и ассоциативный быть

Comment: @teran, а ничего, что последовательность элементов в ассоциативном массиве формально не гарантирована? ;)

Comment: ничего :) можно зато сравнивать в порядке следования ключей, но `$products[$i]` не даст результата. `array_values` вопрос решит, но может добавить сложностей если также требуется знания ключа.

Comment: зы: тогда `ksort`  формально ничего не сортирует? :D

Comment: _тогда ksort формально ничего не сортирует?_ получается так :)

Comment: @teran, Явно указал, на применимость только для индексного массива.